# bash export command that has a variable in it

Tags: bash

I have command that script uses in many loops and want to export it.

```
#!/bin/bash
export COMMAND=$(many programs $FILE)
# And use this command latter like this:
for FILE in ./*; 
do 
eval $"COMMAND"
done
```

And I can't export this command as I get an error from the programs in this COMMAND (please provide the input).

How can I export COMMAND with a variable in it?

**Edit**

I have used @Charles Duffy answer but have an additional problem:

```
your_command() {
do_something_with "$1"
do_something_else_with "$1"
}
export -f your_command


for i in $(seq 1 $Times); do 
  for file in ./*; do
     your_command "$file"
  done 
done
```

When `Times`=1 loop works fine, but when `Times`=2 `your_command` does not save the output (there is an output for the first loop, but not for the second).

Comment: Don't use `seq` -- it isn't standardized by POSIX, and won't always be available (yes, including on some platforms for which bash is present). `for ((i=0; i<Times; i++)); do ...; done` is more reliable.

Comment: The given example doesn't save any kind of output at all, either on the first invocation _or_ on subsequent ones. You'll need to give a better example for your follow-up problem -- or, better, post it as a completely new question, with enough information to reproduce the underlying issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `command` should be a function, not a variable.

```
your_command() {
  do_something_with "$1"
  do_something_else_with "$1"
}

for file in ./*; do
  your_command "$file"
done
```

If you really need this to be exported (available to subprocesses), you can do that with the following:

```
export -f your_command
```

Comment: Agree. `eval` is usually considered too dangerous to be worth it.

Comment: I have edited my question with an additional problem that has emerged.

Answer (score 1):

First off - you should use a function, as described in other answers.  That said, it's possible to fix what you have, too.  You probably shouldn't be using `$()`.  The way you have it, your "many programs" will run immediately when initializing `COMMAND`, and you'll save their *output*, not the command line itself.  Besides that, `$FILE` isn't set yet at that point.  Here's a modified version of your script that should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND='many programs "${FILE}"'
# And use this command later like this:
for FILE in *
do 
  eval ${COMMAND}
done
```

Changes I made to your script:

1. removed unnecessary `export`
2. put `{}` around variable names
3. double-quoted `${FILE}` in case there are files with spaces in their names
4. got rid of the `$()` and replaced it with `''`
5. fixed up indentation for easier reading
6. changed `for` loop list to `*` from `./*` for less typing

Comment: `{}` does much less for safety than appropriate use of double quotes. If something is `$foobar` when it should be `${foo}bar`, it'll fail every time -- but if something is `$foo` when it should be `"$foo"`, that frequently only bites the user when their data is something they didn't test with up-front.

Comment: Unless you have variables `foo` and `foobar`.